# EventClick function in jquery-ui dialogbox not working when button is bound to a function

Tags: jquery, button, modal-dialog

I'm using fullCalendar in conjuction with jquery UI's dialog box.
The problem I am having is with the 'Update' button located in the eventClick() method.  I can never get the alert() to display:"Pressing update should display an alert message".
The Cancel button closes the dialog box as it should.

Ideas ?

---

```
$().ready(function() {
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
                center: 'prevYear title nextYear',
                right: 'prev,next, today'
            },
            theme:true,//use JQuery UI theme
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            weekMode:'variable',
            dayClick:function(){
                //alert('a day has been clicked');
            },
            editable: true,
            eventClick:function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){
                $("#event").dialog({
                    modal:true,
                    title:calEvent.title ,
                    position:'top',
                    width:600,
                    buttons:[
                      {text:'Update',click:function(){updateEvent();}},
                      {text:'Cancel',click:function(){$("#event").dialog('close');}}
                    ]
                });
                $('#title').val(calEvent.title);
                $('#location').val(calEvent.location);
                $('#start').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate($.fullCalendar.parseDate(calEvent.start),'MM/dd/yyyy'));
                if ( calEvent.end != null ) $('#end').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate($.fullCalendar.parseDate(calEvent.end),'MM/dd/yyyy'));
                $('#description').val(calEvent.description);
                $('#uID').val(calEvent.uID);
            },
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                //a new event to be created (1 or more days)    



                var title = prompt('Add a new event:');
                if (title) {
                    var newEvent = {updateType:1,startString:getDateString(start),endString:getDateString(end),title:title,start:start,end:end,allDay:allDay,description:'This is a desc.',location:'Event is at home'};
                    sendDataToCalendar(newEvent);
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent, true);
                }

                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            }
        });

        calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', getEventsFromDB() );


        //setup date picker
        $('#start').datepicker({autoSize:true});
        $('#end').datepicker({autoSize:true});

        //auto update title of dialog box
        $('#title').bind('keyup', function(){
            $('#event').dialog('option', 'title', $('#title').val());
        });
    });


    function updateEvent(){
        alert('Pressing update should display an alert message');
    //  var jsonData = $('#event').serialize() + '&' + $.param({updateType:1});
    //  sendDataToCalendar(jsonData);
    //  $("#event").dialog('close');
    }
```

Comment: The html is dynamically created.  There's not much to show.  The issue is with the jquery ui dialog box.  From within the dialog box, if I hit cancel the eventClick method works properly by closing the dialog box.  If I hit the 'Update' button, nothing happens.  I would like 'Update' to jump to a function (displayed above as well).